# Can't get files of external storage directory

Tags: java, android, io

So I am trying to get all files in a certain directory but I always get a NullPointerException when trying to use file.listFiles()

I have the right permissions included (before the application tags) in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Code:

```
private void moveFiles() {
        String MYTAG = "Mover";
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/_appTests/");
            if(folder.isDirectory()) {  // true
                // get all files
                listFilesForFolder(folder);   // Exception is thrown here
                int amount = 0;
                for (File f : allFiles) {
                    String destDir = getMoveDir(f.getName());
                    try {
                        moveFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), destDir);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(MYTAG, "Error: "+e.getMessage()+" while moving file: "+ f.getName());
                    }
                    Log.i(MYTAG, destDir);
                    amount++;
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "[" + MYTAG + "] Moved " + amount + " files!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(MYTAG, "Moved " + amount + " files!");
            }
        }

}

public void listFilesForFolder(File folder) {
    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) // attempted to get length of a null array
    {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            // recursive call if directory
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            // add to global list
            allFiles.add(fileEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

I can also not access and read a file in the directory *_appTests*, EACCESS Exception (Permission denied) is thrown in this case.

The paths are correct and the directory is also located at */scard/_appTests*.

Do I have to use superuser privileges to access this directory?

App minSdkVersion is 22 (Android 5.1) and I am running Android 6.0 on my phone but I don't use runtime permission request, I include them in my manifest file.

Comment: "I am running Android 6.0 on my phone but I don't use runtime permission request, I include them in my manifest file" -- you always put the permission requests in the manifest. If your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you *also* need to request them at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to manually give STORAGE permission in Settings.

We got the same issue when someone upgraded device to android 6.0 (our app has compileSdk 21 )

Comment: Thank you a lot this really solved it and I hope Google will update the permission system so this permission is automatically granted if you declare this in the manifest file.

Comment: @nauti: It is automatically granted, if your app has `targetSdkVersion` of 22 or lower. Your app presumably has `targetSdkVersion` set to 23 or higher. In that case, you are explicitly telling Android that you *are* intending to use runtime permissions.

Comment: Oh thank you @CommonsWare now I get it.
I always thought you either put them in the manifest OR request runtime permissions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Since you try to access the file it could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permission for reading files too which is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: @Amesys: Still doesn't work and Android Documentation says: 
_However, if your app uses the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, then it implicitly has permission to read the external storage as well._

Comment: @nauti for sdk version 6.0 you need to provide runtime permissions. Do you need help in that?

Comment: No thanks please see aelimill's answer it solved my problem.
And if you provide the _uses-permission_ in the manifest file the app request all required when installing even on Android 6.0.

Comment: @nauti ok Great :)

Answer (score 0):

well the permission in the manifest wont work if you are targeting > sdk 23.
you need to require your permission on runtime for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, File> externalLocations = ExternalStorage.getAllStorageLocations();
File sdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.SD_CARD);
File externalSdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.EXTERNAL_SD_CARD);
```